# How to sort encrypted ArrayList and show this in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

My target is to sort in alphabetical order data from an ArrayList with encrypted data and put correct order into a RecyclerView.
I'm able to show decrypted data into RecyclerView, but in the same order witch I use to add item into the ArrayList (see code in adapter).
I tried to sort with `sortby{}`without success (see code in activity). The result is an partial order and onItemClick not return correct position.

My activity that extend adapter:

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(),DocumentAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

companion object{
    lateinit var dbHandler: DBHandler
}

private var  documentslist = ArrayList<PassItem>()
private lateinit var adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
private lateinit var rv : RecyclerView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    dbHandler = DBHandler(this, null, null,1)

    viewDocuments()

    val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabAdd)
    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val i = Intent(this, AddDocument :: class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }
}

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
private fun viewDocuments(){
    documentslist = dbHandler.getDocuments(this)

    //documentslist.sortBy { it.PassItemApp.toString() } ---> this sort encrypted data then not in alphabetic order and onItemClick return uncorrect position
    
    adapter = DocumentAdapter(this,documentslist,this)
    rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false)
    rv.adapter = adapter
}

override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this@HomeActivity,DocActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("clickedPosition", position)
    startActivity(intent)
}

override fun onResume() {
    viewDocuments()
    super.onResume()
}
```

and my adapter:

```
class DocumentAdapter(val mCtx: Context, private val documents: ArrayList<PassItem>, val listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DocumentAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

interface OnItemClickListener{
    fun onItemClick(position : Int)
}


inner class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener{

    val txtDocApp : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDocApp)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val position : Int = adapterPosition
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
            listener.onItemClick(position)
        }
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DocumentAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_pass_layout,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val document : PassItem = documents[position]

    //Decryption of item showed in Recyclerview
    val initialisationVector = document.PassItemIvApp
    val bytesIV = Base64.decode(initialisationVector, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    val oisIV = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(bytesIV))
    val initializationVectorIV = oisIV.readObject() as ByteArray

    val encryptedText = document.PassItemApp
    val bytesText = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    val oisText = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(bytesText))
    val textByteArray = oisText.readObject() as ByteArray

    val key = document.PassItemKeyApp
    val keyText = Base64.decode(key, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    val oisKey = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(keyText))
    val keyToDecrypt = oisKey.readObject() as SecretKey

    val aesDecrypt = Decrypted(keyToDecrypt,initializationVectorIV)
    val decryptedByteArray = aesDecrypt.decrypt(textByteArray)

    val textAfterDecryption = decryptedByteArray.toString(charset("UTF_8"))

    //Data in Recyclerview
    holder.txtDocApp.text = textAfterDecryption

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return  documents.size
}
```

}

Comment: What is `PassItemApp`? A string? And what order are you getting when using `documentslist.sortBy { it.PassItemApp.toString() }`?

Comment: Hi, Arpit thank you for your interest. Yes, PassItemApp is a String (I add toString() for a request of alphabetical order). The order is the one in which PassItemApp is inserted in the database where it is stored.

Comment: sort function sorts the strings alphabetically so it should have worked. The only problem I can think of when you have strings with both uppercase and lowercase letters. In that case `sort` will put uppercase strings before lowercase ones. To fix this you can use `documentslist.sortBy { it.PassItemApp.lowercase() }`

Comment: @ArpitShukla ok! With lowercase() the order result is correct into RecyclerView, but onItemClick return incorrect position :-( . The position into RecyclerView is the same used on DB when the item has been inserted. Then in the first position I find always the first item inserted

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? What do you expect and what are you actually getting? Something like "When I click the first item I expect position to be 1 but what I get is 0"

Comment: You want your recycler view to show data in alphabetical order but returned position should correspond to the position of that item in database?

Comment: What position do you want upon clicking FOUR? 4?

Comment: @ArpitShukla   Yes! Correct! FOUR( pos 4); ONE (pos 1); TWO (pos 2); THREE (pos 3), but when apply sorby{it.PassItemApp.lowercase()} the resul is: FOUR (pos 1, first alphabetic char) ONE (pos 2); THREE (pos 3 :-)) and TWO (pos 4)

Comment: Got it. So one solution that comes to my mind is to maintain both lists, one which contains original order and second which contains the sorted order, when we get a position in onItemClick, we can search for that item in the originalList and return its index. Will it work for you? The other option is to send the real position of the item to the adapter itself and return that position instead of `adapterPosition` from the click listener